# Migrating MongoDB server from a local machine to AWS EBS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, database-migration, mongodump

I have a mongodb server running locally on a machine and I want to migrate it to AWS EBS. The only option that I found was to use `mongodump` on my local machine and then copy this dump to my EBS machine manually. Is there any other way to do this if I can provide a login into this machine through a VPN and directly take a dump on my remote EBS machine?

Comment: What is the advantage of doing the dump over VPN instead of just copying it via SFTP? When you say EBS do you mean Elastic Block Store? I have a feeling you mean Elastic Beanstalk, which you should not be running a database on.

Comment: Yeah, I mean Elastic Block Store